# Access to ViewBag from a class that inherits from AuthorizationHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I need to access ViewBag from the heir class after AuthorizationHandler.

I need to display the value from the AuthorizationHandler class into the razor view

Comment: You can’t. You have to choose a different storage. The view bag doesn’t exist within an authorization handler because it is a separate concept to Razor views.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is this.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
```

//inside the method that has your data that you want to send to the razor view, add it to the ViewData and not ViewBag

```
var result = context.Result;

if (result is ViewResult) {
if (context.Controller is Controller controller) {
        controller.ViewData["YourData"] = data;
       }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: An [authorization handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.iauthorizationhandler?view=aspnetcore-2.2) does not have [a context that has access to a controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationhandlercontext?view=aspnetcore-2.2). You are probably referring to authorization *filters* here which are a different thing.

Comment: But he could add an auth filter and tie into that